# The C programming Language Exercise 1-14

Tags: c

I have been reading and doing the exercises in the book
The C programming Language by Dennis M.Ritchie

The exercise is the 1-14

Write a program to print a histogram of the frequencies of different characters in its input

```
int c, i, j, k = 0;
int d, ci, nD = 0;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == 'a' || c == 'A')
        ++ci;
    else if (c == 'D' || c == 'd')
        ++nD;
     else if (c == 'B' || c == 'b')
        ++d;
    else if (c == '\n')
      printf("%d %d %d\n", d, ci, nD);
}
```

I have written this piece of code

It counts correctly for D but for A and B it just spits out some numbers

I haven't finished drawing the histogram as these numbers make it hard to do that

Here is the Input

```
Aa Bb Dd
```

Output

```
214732904 2293540 2
```

As for those number aren't they out of range of int type

Comment: This is not a good example of C code.

Comment: `d` and `ci` are not initialized . Initialize them to `0` while declaring.

Comment: And if you would have this comment as your input, how would your program behave?

Comment: You have three separate variables to store the occurrences of the letters a, b and d and you call them `d`, `ci` and `nD`? That's a different naming scheme for each of them. Your solution also doesn't scale to counting all leters. Have you learned about arrays?

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize your variables correctly. If you don't they may contain any starting value.

Change

`int d,ci,nD = 0 ;`

to

`int d = 0, ci = 0, nD = 0 ;`